# An (open?) problem about a sequence of nested principal sub-matrices and their determinants

Tags: reference-request, matrices, determinants, algebraic-combinatorics

**Problem:** Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ integer matrix, $\det(A) = \pm 1$. Under which conditions there exist a nested sequence of [principal submatrices](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/principal+submatrix) of size $n$ such that they all have determinant $\pm 1$ ?

We call such a sequence a $\pm 1$ Principal Minor Sequence ($\pm 1$PMS). Note that such a sequence is described by a permutation of $n$ elements. For example, consider the matrix 
$$ A = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right]. $$
The sequence $(1,2,3)$
$$ A \left[ 1 \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 \end{array} \right], \quad 
A \left[ 1,2 \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1\\ 1 & 1 \end{array} \right], \quad 
A \left[ 1,2,3 \right] = A. $$
is not a $\pm 1$PMS since $\det(A \left[ 1,2 \right])=0$. The sequence $(1,3,2)$ is a $\pm 1$PMS. On the other hand, the matrix
$$ A = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right] $$
does not have any $\pm 1$PMS.

Does anybody know if this problem has already been studied? A related problem is to estimate the number of $\pm 1$PMS of a matrix.

**Note:** It is trivial that a matrix has no $\pm 1$PMS if all its entries in the diagonal are zero.

Comment: Actually, some permutation have all zero entries in the diagonal.  In fact, J-I has such a regular sequence where all but the 1 by 1 matrix has a zero diagonal.  For any regular matrix, determinant computation by Laplace expansion will give you a sequence.  In fact, it will give you at least n! many of them, if you count by original index sets.

Comment: Each time asking "Under which conditions" you should specify in what terms you want an answer. Your desired conclusion **is** a condition!

Comment: repost from MSE http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1240497/an-open-problem-about-a-sequence-of-nested-sub-matrices-and-their-determinant (posted originally only three hours earlier, and already having two answers posted)

Comment: If you compute the adjoint of the matrix, and count the number of nonzero terms of its permanent, that number times n! is what I think is the number of sequences will be, however you may have to compute all the minors to prove this guess.

Comment: Note that this is not just a sequence of minors. They are:
(1) nested;
(2) "symmetric": the indices of the columns and the rows coincide;
(3) "central": the diagonal of the minor lies on the diagonal of the matrix.
I think that I took care enough to avoid this confusion.

Comment: For a positive definite matrix, *every* principal minor is positive.

Comment: Just to show "not always" $$A = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 2 & 4 & 1 \\ 1 & 12 & 3 \end{array} \right]$$ has determinant $50$.